# Does data pass through cache(L3,L2,L1) from RAM before processing it?

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system

I have been reading about cache memory and I found an interesting answer from Quora here

[Cache memory (L1,L2,L3)](https://www.quora.com/Computer-Architecture/What-is-the-L1-L2-L3-cache-of-a-microprocessor-and-how-does-it-affect-the-performance-of-it)

But here I am a bit confused with if CPU wants to process data from RAM so does it pass through like:

**CPU <- Register <- L1 <- L2 <- L3 <- RAM**

Or the instruction directly passes to registers via Memory bus?

Comment: I advice you to take a look to this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/44731/why-are-there-separate-l1-caches-for-data-and-instructions

Comment: Thanks @PatrickTrentin, but now I got more confused like cache also have types like data and instruction cache and also still it's unclear if data moves through cache or not..?

Comment: in general both data and instructions move through cache when possible, in some cases their cache is separated and in some other it is unified. There are plenty of references online if you google about it. :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin.. Yeah I googled and also reading one book of OS and now I think may be CPU first read data from RAM for the first time and then stores it to Cache memory which is required frequently for faster access. And storing that data/instruction depends upon may be size of Caches(L1,..) but priority will be L1 for sure but all I've written is just guessing I'm not sure about it. What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

The definition of a cache is that it's a memory structure that has a lower latency (faster) than the memory below it. Beyond this, you can design a cache system any way you want. For example, when loading a data block from main memory, it can be loaded into all levels of the cache hierarchy and then the requested part of that block is loaded into a register. The exact details depend on the microarchitecture. In addition, the instruction cache and the data cache can have different policies.

Comment: yeah you are right and is it like if CPU wants an instruction from an address first it will check in cache memory (through all levels) and if it doesn't find it will go to main memory for that instruction, and then that word of instruction will be pass to CPU and cache memory too, right? I mean it's a concept, again it depends on the architecture as you said :)

Comment: I think this answer describes "inclusive caches" ; there could also be "exclusive caches" where a cache line can only be present in a single cache level. Or I think I read something like this in Ulrich Drepper's 2007 paper (P.16).

Comment: @wil I didn't mention inclusive caches explicitly. Although inclusive caches are common. I was just giving an example. The most important part of the answer is "this is a design-specific aspect".

Comment: @wil There are also caches that are neither inclusive nor exclusive. There are many, many options.

Comment: Thank you for the precision, I do not understand fully those definitions yet. I also do not know all the possible architectures there could be.

Comment: @Hiren If this answers your question, you can click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons to accept the answer.